# How to override Free shipping method to charge $25 shipping charge instead?

Tags: free-shipping

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto
13 Amasty extensions
```

I offer special *'Expedited Christmas is guaranteed for orders by 12/20'* shipping option for $25. Last Christmas, we set it up via the Shipping Rules Amasty extension which connected through the  [freeshipping] shipping option where the price was overriden directly in the 'Expedited Christmas Shipping' Amasty Shipping rule where it is set in Rates = Base Rate for the Order: 25

I have updated things yesterday and now, when I try to activate this 'Expedited Christmas' Shipping rule via the Free Shipping Flat rate - it shows up on the front end but wants to charge $0 instead of the $25.

**Is there a way to override the Free shipping in Magento NOT to be $0 but to charge $25 instead?** I think this will be the only way for me to do this as the other Flat shipping methods are used up for Amasty's Shipping Rules and Shipping Restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by adding the 'Expedited Christmas is guaranteed for orders by 12/21 [freeshipping]' Free shipping option into the 'Block nationwide' Shipping Restriction next to Best Way [tablerate].